# Any Button Stops Timer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have two timers that run in Visual Studio and one works perfectly fine, but the other stops whenever i hit any key while it's running, if i don't hit any key, it works fine.  Sorry if the codes messy im new at this XD.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If PictureBox2.Top = 277 Then
        Label3.Text = "Label3"
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W And Label3.Text = "Label3" Or Label3.Text = "single" And e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        PictureBox2.Top = PictureBox2.Top - 64
    End If
    If PictureBox2.Top = 213 Then
        Label3.Text = "single"
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        Label1.Text = "0"
    End If
    If Label1.Text = "0" And Label3.Text = "single" Then
        Label2.Text = "0"
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
    If PictureBox2.Top = 149 Then
        Label3.Text = "double"
    End If
    If Label3.Text = "double" Then
        Timer2.Enabled = True And Label2.Text = "0"
    End If
End Sub
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
    If Label1.Text = "30" Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
    If Timer1.Enabled = False And Label3.Text = "single" Then
        PictureBox2.Top = PictureBox2.Top + 64
    End If
End Sub
Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Timer2 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
    If Label3.Text = "double" Then
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End If
    If Label2.Text = "30" Then
        Timer2.Enabled = False
    End If
    If Timer2.Enabled = False And Label3.Text = "double" Then
        PictureBox2.Top = PictureBox2.Top + 128
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which one is not working properly Timer1 or Timer2?

Comment: Are the labels rendered at the form or do you use them to store text? Because if you use them to store and keep track of text you're really doing something unnecessary. You should be using a `String` for that. Ex: `Dim check1 As String`, setting: `check1 = "single"`.

Comment: Let me ask one more thing: Why do you have multiple if statements checking the exact same thing? You check if `e.KeyCode` equals to `Keys.W` in three different statements. Just enclose everything into one statement, only checking `e.KeyCode` once.

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file or enable it in the project's properties.  This line:  `Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1` makes no sense.  You are trying to perform addition on a string type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a vb.net person and so I could be completely off base and downvoted for it, but this line looks wrong: 
`Timer2.Enabled = True And Label2.Text = "0"`

In a sane language, that will be treated as :

Set Time2.Enabled to the right side value, (`True and Label2.Text = "0"`)
   `True and [Anything]` is logically `[Anything]` ... assuming Label2.Text was not "0", this will therefore set `Timer2.Enabled` to be false, which is probably not what you wanted

There may be other issues with this code, but I'd start with that one.

Comment: You're right about that, Foon. @PJMichalski : **You should ONLY use AND in the EXPRESSION OF AN IF-STATEMENT.** That means here: `If [only use And here] Then`.